# DataGrid disables the ability to edit other rows other than one initially selected

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a datagrid that populates 5 columns and at run time i add entry to them.
Here, the first 2 columns must be always disabled/locked so I wanted to set ReadOnly for those columns. Hence, I enabled DataGridCell.Selected="DataGridGotFocus" in below xaml.

```
<DataGrid  Name="dataGrid1" DataGridCell.Selected="DataGridGotFocus" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CollectionList}"                    
  SelectionMode="Single" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray" AlternationCount="2" DockPanel.Dock="Right" CanUserAddRows="False"/>
```

and my xaml.cs file has the below

```
private void DataGridGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            dataGrid1.Columns[0].IsReadOnly = true;
            dataGrid1.Columns[1].IsReadOnly = true;
            dataGrid1.Columns[2].IsReadOnly = false;
            dataGrid1.Columns[3].IsReadOnly = false;
            dataGrid1.Columns[4].IsReadOnly = false;

    }
```

The issue here is, when for the first time i click any row, I'm able to edit the values for that row's cell but every other row is locked and i'm unable to edit.
Also, initially i went on to click every cell in different rows, it opened up for edit but the moment i type in anything, only that row is enabled all time. Every other row, gets disabled. Please, kindly help me here.

Why rows are not editable?

Appreciate any help!

Edit: I need to enable editing on all my rows. Should i specify any property explicitly? Or is my xaml just fine?

Edit: Looks like, setting DataGridCell.Selected="DataGridGotFocus" is not an issue. When I retried without setting them, i still couldn't edit my rows.

Comment: when you create each column can't you just set it to readonly right away?

Comment: I pass values by binding them to ItemSource. So I can't set it in the xaml as only first 2 columns needs to be turned true.

Comment: Do you want to allow only first two column values to be edited, correct?

Comment: @GaurangDave: Nope, First two columns should be disabled(not-editable) which I'm already achieving by setting ReadOnly=true. But major issue here is, i need to edit all my rows. Only the first row which i click is editable others are disabled. Am i doing something wrong in xaml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The issue seems to be validation issue. I seemed to have always given incorrect value to the one of the cell in that one row which was editable and DataGrid won't exit the edit mode when the cell validation fails. So, that was the issue. But there was no hint and hence it was hard for me to understand what was going on.
Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that the columns are being generated automatically you can use AutoGeneratingColumn event which "gives you the option of altering each generated column before it is added to the control." (see [DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn(v=vs.95).aspx))
So you may do it like:

```
private void dataGrid1_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "FirstColumnProp")
    {
        e.Column.IsReadOnly = true;
    }
    else if ...
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are letting the DataGrid generate the columns for you automatically. This is an easy setting to see the rows quickly but does not let you customize your DataGrid. I would specify the columns specifically that way you can set which ones you want readonly or not.  Note the `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`

```
<DataGrid  
    Name="dataGrid1" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataGridCell.Selected="DataGridGotFocus" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CollectionList}"
    SelectionMode="Single" 
    AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray" 
    AlternationCount="2" 
    DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
    CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn
        Header="Column 1"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        Binding="{Binding ...}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn
        Header="Column 2"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        Binding="{Binding ...}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn
        Header="Column 3"
        Binding="{Binding ...}"/>
    ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Well, it does'nt actually seem to be an issue with setting DataGridCell.Selected. When I re-tried without this option, i still couldnt edit my rows. Whats with my rows being disabled? Any idea?

Comment: Even for columns that are marked `IsReadonly="False"` ??

Comment: The issue seems to be validation issue. Giving correct values solved my issue. Thanks!